# Rotation issue with my app

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation

I am building an test app where the user can search for a book using the Google Books API.

Here how it looks like.

[image: portrait mode]

When I rotate the phone then listview is gone. I have to type again a book's name and see the new data. So during the rotation part,the activity is destroyed as well as my web request to the server.

So let me share you my code. First I have my Book class which implements Parcelable

```
public class Book implements Parcelable{

private String title;
private String author;
private String imageUrl;

protected Book(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    author = in.readString();
    imageUrl = in.readString();

}

public static final Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Creator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Book(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Book[size];
    }
};

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}



/**
 *
 * @param title is the title of the book
 * @param author is the author of the book
 */
public Book(String title,String author,String imageUrl){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

}

// Returns title
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
// Returns author
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeString(author);
    parcel.writeString(imageUrl);

}
```

}

And my MainActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public static final String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
BookAdapter adapter;
EditText searchText;
Button searchButton;
String search;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);


        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                search = searchText.getText().toString();

                String url = URL + search + "&maxResults=15";


                BookAsyncTask bookAsyncTask = new BookAsyncTask();
                bookAsyncTask.execute(url);

                adapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bookList, R.color.list_color);

                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

}

/*
public void searchBook(View view){


}
*/



private class BookAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Book>>{

    @Override
    protected List<Book> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        if (urls.length < 1 || urls[0] == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Book> result = QueryUtils.fetchBookData(urls[0]);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Book> books) {
        adapter.clear();

        if(books != null && !books.isEmpty()){
            adapter.addAll(books);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key",bookList);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    bookList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
}
}
```

As you can see I am overriding the onSaveInstantState(..) method where the list data are stored(I checked it with the debugger),and the onRestoreInstanceState(...)

Any ideas how to fix my problem?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: you can add  android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity in the manifest @Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your manifest

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="my activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Comment: @Theo ur Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

> Include this in your manifest if you dont want to override config change

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" >
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a new activity.in landscape mode so that the screen can be fine for both screen orientation.Or if you want to let it remain as portrait then add this code in you manifest to the activity you want to remain a portrait

```
 android:screenOrientation="portait"
```